# How to use GROUP_CONCAT and/or NEST but limit number of elements in the result

Tags: google-bigquery

I am regularly aggregating metrics for tables of users, where the size of each aggregated group bucket is in the order of tens of thousands. I'd like to be able to provide a few example users for each bucket, but not a `GROUP_CONCAT` with length of thousands or potentially millions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with legacy SQL aggregate functions, but it is possible with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) and its aggregate functions `STRING_AGG` (corresponds to `GROUP_CONCAT` in legacy SQL) and `ARRAY_AGG` (corresponds to `NEST`). Both of these functions support optional `LIMIT` clause as documented in "[Using LIMIT with aggregate functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#using-limit-with-aggregate-functions)".

For example:

```
select string_agg(x LIMIT 2) 
from unnest(['hello', 'world!', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']) x
```

returns `'hello,world!'` string, and

```
select array_agg(x LIMIT 2) 
from unnest(['hello', 'world!', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']) x
```

returns `['hello', 'world!']` array.

Answer (score 0):

For `Legacy SQL`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(x) FROM (
  SELECT x FROM 
    (SELECT 'hello' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'world!' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'foo' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'bar' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'baz' AS x),
LIMIT 2
)
```

and

```
SELECT NEST(x) FROM (
  SELECT x FROM 
    (SELECT 'hello' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'world!' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'foo' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'bar' AS x), 
    (SELECT 'baz' AS x),
LIMIT 2
)
```

they respectively return `'hello,world!'` string and `['hello', 'world!']` "array"

below is example with GROUP BY

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(x) FROM (
  SELECT id, x, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS num FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS id, 'hello' AS x), 
    (SELECT 1 AS id, 'world!' AS x), 
    (SELECT 1 AS id, 'foo' AS x), 
    (SELECT 1 AS id, 'bar' AS x), 
    (SELECT 1 AS id, 'baz' AS x),
    (SELECT 2 AS id, 'hello2' AS x), 
    (SELECT 2 AS id, 'world2!' AS x), 
    (SELECT 2 AS id, 'foo2' AS x), 
    (SELECT 2 AS id, 'bar2' AS x), 
    (SELECT 2 AS id, 'baz2' AS x),
)  
WHERE num < 3
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: However, this solution won't work with GROUP BY which was part of the original question (but examples for simplicity omitted it).

Comment: added example with `GROUP BY`